# Windows 10 does not remember icon position

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

Running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit v1803.

Missing context menu items `View > Auto arrange` and `View > Align to grid` have been restored (using the tips in [this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14856-enable-disable-auto-arrange-folders-windows-10-a.html)). `View > auto arrange` is switched off, and `View > Align to grid` is on.

I've set up a special "Work-Shortcuts" folder and want to arrange the icons to specific locations. This dramatically improves productivity and was a great feature in Windows XP. For example, here is the initial position:

[image: Initial position]

Now I move the icons to where I need them:

[image: Icons are now in the perfect position!]

Everything looks good...but after closing and re-opening the folder (or just hit `F5`) all the icons return to the position shown in the first image! It appears that `Auto arrange` is on (even though it is not ticked) or Windows has failed to save the folder settings (I believe these are called `ShellBag`).

How do I force Windows to save my icon positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Desktop has the ability to retain icon position information, File Explorer windows do not.

There have been other similar questions [asked elsewhere](https://www.tenforums.com/customization/77150-how-save-icon-positions-windows-file-explorer-promise-left-nut.html) online and so far there is no utility I am aware of that adds this ability.

Comment: Has Microsoft really broken or removed this crucial functionality? This was a major productivity feature of early versions of Windows 10 (certainly v1607) and Windows XP (I'm assuming Windows 7 too).

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer appears to be correct. Microsoft has removed this useful feature of earlier versions of Windows. A shame. My workaround is to use the ability to retain icon positions of the desktop and Windows > Start menu. In each sub-folder from the desktop, select `View > Medium icons` and `View > Algin to grid` (the latter may be redundant).